# Python using datetime and timedelta returning datetime object

Tags: python, string, datetime, timedelta

I want to get the datetime(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM) from 10 minutes ago, but when I use timedelta, it converts it to string.
Is there a way to make this simpler?

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

startRaw = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)
start = startRaw.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

print(type(start))
<type 'str'>

start = datetime.strptime(start,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

print(type(start)) 
<type 'datetime.datetime'>


print(start) 
2020-01-21 19:48:00
```

Comment: timedelta do not convert datetime to string.
you convert it here `start = startRaw.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LinnTroll state, the `start = startRaw.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` converts the `datatime` object to string. You can just simply use the `starRaw`.

```
startRaw = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)
print(type(startRaw))
print(startRaw)
```

The outputs are:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2020-01-21 12:04:12.40710
```